# How to make mobx observer context change

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

When use context with mobx. The Component cannot observer context change.

Example(Just a simply demo):

```
const Context = createContext({})

class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Context.Provider value={this.state.value}> // when value changed
        <Child/>
      </Context.Provider>
    )
  }
}

@observer
class Child extends Component {   
  // ... some other observable properties
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.context} // here not changed
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

When context provider value changed, `Child` with `@observer` cannot update. How to fix this.

Comment: ,how are you changing the state ? Make sure you are using actions to change the state.It should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mobx @observer won't observe React Context changes.
If you want your component to change on context changes, please use the default

```
<Context.Consumer>
  /* your component code here */
</Context.Consumer>
```

Component.

You can mix `@observer` and `<Context.Consumer>` in your component.

```
@observer
class Child extends Component {   
  // ... some other observable properties
  render() {
    return (
      <Context.Consumer>
        {value  /* value from context */=> <div>{value}</div>}
      </Context.Consumer>
    )
  }
}
```

References

- https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer